# How to combine flowjs type definitions

Tags: flow-js

How can I combine the following type definitions, so I dont have to repeat myself?

```
type Lama = {|
name: string,
|};

type LamaWithHat = {|
name: string,
hat: string,
|};
```

Tried using [Interseptions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/) but appearently the syntax might be wrong:

```
type LamaWithHat = {|
hat: string,
|} & Lama;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if we do this
/* @flow */

```
type Lama = {|
name: string,
|};

type LamaWithHat = {|
...Lama,
hat: string,
|};

const a: Lama = {
    name: 'rahul'
}

const b: LamaWithHat = {
    name: 'rahul',
    hat: 'circluar'
}
```

test this code here
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAyAhgLbFgC8YA3gD6oB2ZeAXGAM4YBOAlowHMANKjoBfANzps+ImWIB1XhgAWACWIYqtBgDp9JciJWb2XPoJHipqAMZxGXMMXaGK1GqjDewzUmzAAcm5iFQBXGEDUMXR7Ry0AI1d5JVUNLQ8vHz8A4NCIwJEfMBMMdkDbXm5bGDDibiixIA